# getting attendants of a recorded meeting in adobeconnect

Tags: adobe-connect

I'm trying to get attendants of only one recording of a meeting
I'm able to get records with `sco-contents` and get attendants of a meeting by `report-meeting-attendance`

but `report-meeting-attendance` returns all of attendants in all recordings of a meeting and I cant filter it by recording `scoid`(it returns empty)

how can I get attendants of single recording of a meeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `report-event-participants-complete-information` with your meeting `sco-id` as parameter.

Find more information about It [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/webservices/report-event-participants-complete-information.html).